# Usergrid: how to stream a long list of connections?

Tags: usergrid

Let's say I have some collection called `someentity` that has connections to other entities via a verb `subscribedto`.  For a particular entity with id `some_id`, I'd like to pull all the entities that are connected to this entity via the `subscribedto` verb.  I can do that via this GET request:

`/org/app/someentity/some_id/subscribedto`

However, I'm not sure how I stream or page through this data if there are thousands or more results.  I'm not getting back a cursor or anything.  Is having a huge number of connections to a particular entity something that's just not a smart thing to do with Usergrid?

Comment: If there are more entities than what's specified in the `limit` param of your request, you should get back a `cursor` prop in the response body. Is that not what you're seeing?

Comment: @amuramoto I wasn't clear when I originally posted, but I meant querying for incoming connections.  I left out the crucial `connecting` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a bug.  I did not phrase my original question well, as I did not make it clear that this is a bug for INCOMING connections.  See here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/USERGRID-1310